# Sequelize(Postgresql) where condition only for subquery + inner join only for subquery and left outer join for outer query

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

```
table name: user
columns: user_id, name(varchar)

table name: book
columns: book_id, name(varchar)

table name: publisher
columns: publisher_id, user_id(fk to user table), book_id(fk to book table)
```

I need to get user table left outer join with book table. And search for if user.name or book.name contains `jack` by using full-text search. The return query must also return the book info if the user_id is in publisher(even when user.name don't contain the text `jack` but the book contain the name `jack`)

desired query:

```
SELECT "users".*,
    "publishers"."publisher_id" AS "publishers.publisher_id",
    "publishers->book"."book_id" AS "publishers.book.book_id",
    "publishers->book"."name" AS "publishers.book.name",
FROM
    (SELECT "users"."id" AS "id",
            "users"."name" AS "name",
        FROM "user" AS "users"
        WHERE ((TO_TSVECTOR('simple',

                                        TRANSLATE("users"."name",

                                            '/`~!@#$%^&*()_|+-=?;:''",.<>{}[]\/]',
                                            '                                   ')) @@ 'jack:*')
               OR
               (SELECT "publishers"."user_id"
                    FROM "publisher" AS "publishers"
                    INNER JOIN "book" AS "book" ON "publishers"."book_id" = "book"."book_id"
                    AND (TO_TSVECTOR('simple',

                                            TRANSLATE("book"."name",

                                                '/`~!@#$%^&*()_|+-=?;:''",.<>{}[]\/]',
                                                '                                   ')) @@ 'jack:*')
                    WHERE ("publishers"."user_id" = "users"."user_id")
                    LIMIT 1) IS NOT NULL)
                
        GROUP BY "users"."user_id"
        ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC
        LIMIT 20
        OFFSET 0) AS "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "publisher" AS "publishers" ON "users"."user_id" = "publishers"."user_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "book" AS "publishers->book" ON "publishers"."book_id" = "publishers->book"."book_id"
ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC;
```

Here is the query I tried:

```
UserModel.findAndCountAll(
   options: {
      where: {
          custom_text_search_function('jack')
      }
      order: [ [ 'name', 'ASC' ] ],
      group: [ 'UserModel.user_id' ],
      include: [ 
              { 
                 model: PubisherModel, 
                 include: [
                      {
                          model: BookModel,
                          where: {
                             custom_text_search_function('jack')
                          }
                          required: false,
                      }
                 ] 
              } 
      ]
   }
   limit: 20,
   offset: 0,
)
```

But the query I got was a different one:

```
SELECT "users".*,
        "publishers"."publisher_id" AS "publishers.publisher_id",
        "publishers->book"."book_id" AS "publishers.book.book_id",
        "publishers->book"."name" AS "publishers.book.name",
FROM
    (SELECT "users"."id" AS "id",
                "users"."name" AS "name",
        FROM "user" AS "users"
        WHERE (TO_TSVECTOR('simple',

                                        TRANSLATE("users"."name",

                                            '/`~!@#$%^&*()_|+-=?;:''",.<>{}[]\/]',
                                            '                                   ')) @@ 'jack:*')
        GROUP BY "users"."user_id"
        ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC
        LIMIT 20
        OFFSET 0) AS "users"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "publisher" AS "publishers" ON "users"."user_id" = "publishers"."user_id"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "book" AS "publishers->book" ON "publishers"."book_id" = "publishers->book"."book_id"
AND (TO_TSVECTOR('simple',

                        TRANSLATE("publishers->book"."name",

                            '/`~!@#$%^&*()_|+-=?;:''",.<>{}[]\/]',
                            '                                   ')) @@ 'jack:*')
ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC;
```

which is not I wanted because this filtered out the user that user_id not exists in publishers table. And it doesn't have the where condition in the subquery with INNER JOIN(instead it's outside on the LEFT OUTER JOIN) -> not what I wanted

How can I turn this sequelize query into the one I desired?